# Changing multisample count or disable/enable multisampling while the program runs?

Tags: xna

How can I disable or enable multi-sampling live while the program is rendering?

I tried this.

```
    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.MultiSampleCount = 0;

        ... draw stuff ...

    }
```

But it doesn't disable the multisampling while drawing, because setting "PreferMultiSampling" to true under the presentation parameters when starting the program apparently overwrites this. Or am I wrong?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PresentationParameters` tells you the current settings of the `GraphicsDevice`. It's a readout. You're not supposed to modify it.

You need to change the settings on the `GraphicsDeviceManager` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphicsdevicemanager_members.aspx), the default template creates one called `graphics` as a member of your `Game` class), and then call `ApplyChanges()`.